# How to find mushrooms in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to make the regeneration suspicious stew. I can find the flower easily (I live in a plains biome), but the mushrooms are impossible to find. Where could I find them?

Comment: The nether roof or a mushroom island are usually the best places to find mushrooms, as well roofed forests, some caves. If you have the seed, you can use a biome finder to locate the nearest mushroom island.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find mushrooms in these areas:

1. Caves with less then twelve light levels
2. Sideways logs in forests sometimes
3. Swamps, giant tree taiga, mushroom biomes, and commonly in the Nether
4. Leaves of trees occasionally

I found this information from [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mushroom).

Answer (score 2):

It's faster getting mushrooms by heading over to the nether or in caves. They seem to naturally grow in the world generation progress, and it makes sense why there are mushrooms in the nether (as of v.1.16).

Answer (score -1):

In a roofed forest there are occasionally giant mushrooms. Or you can look for a mushroom island biome. You can also find mushrooms in the nether.